# Фильтр на изображение

Tags: php, изображения

Использую PHP создаю из двух картинок и текста (функция imagettftext) одну картинку (функция imagejpeg).

Сейчас появилась задача помимо обычного соединения и изменения размеров, нужно наложить какой - нибудь фильтр. К примеру, нужно чтобы первоначальная картинка была как бы нарисована красками.

В какую сторону смотреть (в библиотеки http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.image.php плохо еще разбираюсь)? Как можно реализовать это с помощью PHP ?

Comment: Вот неплохая библиотека - https://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_samples.htm

Comment: к сожалению, там нет подобного фильтра